# Python/Pillow: scale child image, but maintain parent image dimensions

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have been able to use .thumbnail to scale the entire image, but I'd to scale the image, and preserve the original dimensions as depicted in the second transformation below:

[image]

Comment: how about you dump the thumbnail into a bigger buffer?, not sure how to do it with pillow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Daniel said, you can create the thumbnail image using `.thumbnail()`, create an new image with same size of the original image and then paste the thumbnail into the new image:

```
def scale_image(img, factor, bgcolor):
    # create new image with same mode and size as the original image
    out = PIL.Image.new(img.mode, img.size, bgcolor)
    # determine the thumbnail size
    tw = int(img.width * factor)
    th = int(img.height * factor)
    # determine the position
    x = (img.width - tw) // 2
    y = (img.height - th) // 2
    # create the thumbnail image and paste into new image
    img.thumbnail((tw,th))
    out.paste(img, (x,y))
    return out
```

`factor` should be between 0 and 1, and `bgcolor` is the background color of the new image.

Example:

```
img = PIL.Image.open('image.jpg')
new_img = scale_image(img, 0.5, 'white')
new_img.show()
```